# Go to another URL when form is completed

Tags: java, html

So I have an HTML form and I want the submit button to not only submit the data (which it does) but also redirect the client to index.html. However, it is not working. This is what I currently have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

function clickedButton() {
    window.location = 'index.html'
}
</script>

<input type="submit" onClick="javascript:clickedButton()" name="submit" value="Submit" >
```

Comment: The HTML form should already have an action to send you to the results page, if it's not set it defaults to refresh the one the form is on. Why not set the form action equal to the page you want it to redirect them to?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Answer (score 0):

Cant you follow the below approach.

```
<form method="post" action="index.html">
<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: Nope, in my form I am already using action to submit the data in the form

**<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">**

Comment: Try the below code:
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
                  function clickedButton()
            {
                window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
            }
        </script>

<input type="submit" onClick="javascript:clickedButton()" name="submit" value="Submit" >

Comment: Can you please post the code that you used after my suggestion

Comment: I am able to do it without any issues in IE, Chrome

Comment: For my situation this is not an option. The action is already reserved for PHP.

Comment: The only thing I can think of at this point is "Is javascript enabled on your browser". Follow the link http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/display-different-content-if-javascript-is-disabled/ and let us know the output

Answer (score 0):

The code that a user commented above worked for me (

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"> 
function clickedButton() { window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); }
</script>
<input type="submit" onClick="javascript:clickedButton()" name="submit" value="Submit">

</html>
```

)

But remember to make sure your browser lets you redirect to other pages from clickedButton(). In my case, Internet Explorer blocked it by default (not that I should be using IE...)

Comment: I have tried all 3 of my browsers, this code does not work.